# `sed` regexp error

Tags: linux, sed, docker

I'm trying to write an alias to get the ip of a docker container.
The command is the following:

```
docker inspect redis | grep IPAddress | awk 'NR==3{ print $2 }' | sed 's/[^"]*"\([^"]*\)".*/\1/'
```

If I launch it from command line it works properly.
Then I inserted it into `bash_aliases`:

```
alias redis-ip="docker inspect redis | grep IPAddress | awk 'NR==3{ print $2 }' | sed 's/[^"]*"\([^"]*\)".*/\1/'"
```

But when I launch `redis-ip` I get this error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 19: invalid reference \1 on `s' command's RHS
```

Anyone can tell me what is the error about?

Comment: It is probably related to first quotation mark you have when defining alias, it groups this as the first quoted group

    "docker inspect redis | grep IPAddress | awk 'NR==3{ print $2 }' | sed 's/[^" so it is missing quotation marks, as it doesn't intepret the command the same as when you run it manually

Comment: Also the grep|awk|sed can be done in a single awk command

Comment: @123 If you'd like to post here a shorter solution it would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do use a shell function for this rather than an alias:

```
function redis-ip {
  docker inspect redis |
  grep IPAddress |
  awk 'NR == 3 { print $2 }' |
  sed 's/[^"]*"\([^"]*\)".*/\1/'
}
```

If the `sed` does what you want or not, I don't know as I don't know what the `docker` command outputs.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you have your alias enclosed in double quotes (`"`). This means that the `$2` in your `awk` script is passed to the shell and not to `awk` and that the double quotes in your `sed` command are screwing your alias up. Your alias should work as expected if you do this instead:

`alias redis-ip="docker inspect redis | grep IPAddress | awk 'NR==3{print \$2 }' | sed 's/[^\"]*\"\([^\"]*\)\".*/\1/'"`

Probably better and certainly simpler to [use a function](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/298599/22222) though.

Comment: As no shell variables are being used, it would probably be easier to single quote the whole thing.

Comment: @123 you'd still have to escape the double quotes in the `sed` expression since single quoting would mean you have to double quote the `sed` but yes, at least you wouldn't need to escape the `$2`.

Comment: @123 on second thought, it wouldn't make any difference. The `$2` would still need to be escaped since it would now be in a double-quoted awk script.

Answer (score 1):

Ordinarily, I'd say "use jq or jsonpipe or similar if you want to parse or extract data from json", but the `docker inspect` command already has built-in output formatting and field extraction.

You can tell `docker inspect` to return just the field(s) you're interested in, e.g.

```
alias redis-ip="docker inspect -f '{{.NetworkSettings.IPAddress}}' redis"
```

or

```
alias redis-ip='docker inspect -f '\''{{.NetworkSettings.IPAddress}}'\'' redis'
```

This is (tersely) documented at https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/inspect/

See also [What to Inspect When You're Inspecting](https://www.ctl.io/developers/blog/post/what-to-inspect-when-youre-inspecting/) for more details and examples.  And [Docker Inspect Template Magic](http://container-solutions.com/docker-inspect-template-magic/) is another blog post with a nice overview of what's possible with docker inspect output formatting, and several more useful examples.